# Integrate with already existing Users table

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

I have an application where users can login, I would like that existing users will be able to login in Wekan. How I can implement this ?
Is there an available an LDAP login or similar ?

Thanks.

Comment: you can alter the LoginForm to use the [ldap](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php) extension for php.
i would also import all users after successfull auth to keep things simple anytime you need to use `Yii::$app->user->identity`

Comment: Do you need an information for yii2 or for [wekan](https://wekan.github.io/), the meteor trello clone, or something totally different?

Comment: You should try using their REST APIs https://github.com/wekan/wekan/wiki/REST-API

Comment: this does not look a question related to yii2